# Como enviar texto formatado com TidMessage smtp e richedit

Tags: delphi, email, smtp

Olá. Estou a tentar mandar um e-mail com texto formatado a utilizar o meu programa delphi só que ao invés de ser enviado um texto é enviado um ficheiro .trx como anexo.
estou a utilizar: **TidMEssage -> IdMsgSend // tidSMTP // RichEdit**

o codigo de envio é  seguinte:

```
with(TIdText.Create(IdMsgSend.MessageParts,nil))do
begin
   IdMsgSend.ContentType := 'text/RichEdit';
   RichEdit.Lines.SaveToFile('FileRTF.rtf');
   IdMsgSend.Body.LoadFromFile('FileRTF.rtf');
end;
```

...

a parte de envio é assim

```
    try
       SMTP.ConnectTimeout:=15000;
       SMTP.ReadTimeout:=15000;
       SMTP.Connect;
       SMTP.Send(IdMsgSend);
       Self.Tag:=1;
    except
    on E:Exception do
       ShowMessage(E.Message) ;
   end;
```

no ficheiro trx que vai em anexo tem esta formatação

[image: Imagem Fihcheiro .trx]

ja tentei coisas como ao invés de carregar de um ficheiro fazer atribuições diretas e passagem por stream. O resultado final é o mesmo. Ao inves de texto formatado é passado em anexo um ficheiro .trx com as formatações. Algo que me está a escapar? 
Obrigado.

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei, o jeito é enviar como `HTML`. Já tentou? Teria primeiro que converter o `RTF` para `HTML` e depois enviar, sendo que o `ContentType` deveria ser alterado para **text/html**.

Comment: Isso significa formatar o texto entre tags?

Comment: Amigo, veja os seguintes links: [SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397509/6840825). Esse link não testei, mas pela aceitação dele no _SOen_, parece ser interessante.  
Esse outro [Link](http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/converter-de-rtf-para-html-e-enviar-por-email/297471) é referente meu primeiro comentário, veja como primeiro é salvo em `Word`, para converter para `HTML` e depois enviado por e-mail. É meio gambiarra, mas pode funcionar.  
Resumindo, `RTF` apenas no `Microsoft Outlook` (ou parecidos), o resto tem que ser `HTML`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! A primeira opção já tinha testado mas ele tem o mesmo comportamento. Vou agora tentar fazer a conversão pra html e ver como ele se comporta. Assim que encontrar alguma solução eu coloco aqui. isso se encontrar....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa função resolveu o meu problema visto que estava a exportar de uma RichEdit...

```
function TFEnviarMailDirecto.RtfToHtml(RICH: TcxRichEdit): string;
var
  I,J,max_array: integer;
  html: string;
  F,FO: array [0..5] of string;
  str,lgt: integer;
  size,breaklines: integer;
  cor : string;
begin
  html := '';
  str := rich.SelStart;
  lgt := rich.SelLength;
  MAX_ARRAY := 5;
  breaklines:=0;



 for J := 0 to MAX_ARRAY do
  begin
    F[J] := '';
    FO[J] := '';
  end;



for I := 0 to length(RICH.text) do
  begin
    RICH.SelStart := I-BREAKLINES;
    RICH.SelLength := 1;
for J := 0 to MAX_ARRAY do
  FO[J] := F[J];

if (RICH.SelAttributes.Style - [fsItalic] - [fsUnderline] - [fsStrikeOut] = [fsBold]) then
  F[0] := '<b>'
else
  F[0] := '</b>';

if (RICH.SelAttributes.Style - [fsItalic] - [fsBold] - [fsStrikeOut] = [fsUnderline]) then
  F[1] := '<u>'
else
  F[1] := '</u>';

if (RICH.SelAttributes.Style - [fsUnderline] - [fsBold] - [fsStrikeOut] = [fsItalic]) then
  F[2] := '<i>'
else
  F[2] := '</i>';

if RICH.SelAttributes.size < 10 then
  SIZE := 1
else if RICH.SelAttributes.size < 12 then
  SIZE := 2
else if RICH.SelAttributes.size < 14 then
  SIZE := 3
else if RICH.SelAttributes.size < 18 then
  SIZE := 4
else if RICH.SelAttributes.size < 22 then
  SIZE := 5
else if RICH.SelAttributes.size < 32 then
  SIZE := 6
else
  SIZE := 7;
COR := ColorToString(RICH.SelAttributes.Color);
if (COR = 'clWindowText') or (COR = 'clBlack') then
  COR := '#000000'
else if COR = 'clWite' then
  COR := '#FFFFFF'
else if COR = 'clAqua' then
  COR := '#00FFFF'
else if COR = 'clFuchsia' then
  COR := '#FF00FF'
else if COR = 'clBlue' then
  COR := '#0000FF'
else if COR = 'clYellow' then
  COR := '#FFFF00'
else if COR = 'clLime' then
  COR := '#00FF00'
else if COR = 'clRed' then
  COR := '#FF0000'
else if COR = 'clSilver' then
  COR := '#C0C0C0'
else if COR = 'clGray' then
  COR := '#808080'
else if COR = 'clTeal' then
  COR := '#008080'
else if COR = 'clPurple' then
  COR := '#800080'
else if COR = 'clNavy' then
  COR := '#000080'
else if COR = 'clOlive' then
  COR := '#808000'
else if COR = 'clGreen' then
  COR := '#008000'
else if COR = 'clMaroon' then
  COR := '#800000'
else if copy(COR,1,1) = '$' then
  COR := '#'+copy(COR,length(COR)-1,2)
            +copy(COR,length(COR)-3,2)
            +copy(COR,length(COR)-5,2)
else
  COR := '#000000';
F[3] := '</font><font face="'+RICH.SelAttributes.Name+'" size='+inttostr(SIZE)+' color="'+COR+'">';

if RICH.Paragraph.Alignment = taCenter then
  F[4] := '<center>'
else
  F[4] := '</center>';

if RICH.Paragraph.Alignment = taRightJustify then
  F[5] := '<div align="right">'
else
  F[5] := '</div>';

for J := 0 to MAX_ARRAY do
  if FO[J] <> F[J] then
    HTML := HTML + F[J];

if copy(RICH.text,I+1,1) = #13 then
begin
  inc(BREAKLINES); 
  HTML := HTML + '<br>';
end;

HTML := HTML + copy(RICH.text,I+1,1);
  end;
  RICH.SelStart := STR;
  RICH.SelLength := LGT;

  result := HTML;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, caso opte por formatar em HTML no corpo do e-mail, sugiro a leitura [deste post](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/rlebeau/2005_08_17_a.en.aspx), pois a forma como manipular os objetos do indy pode variar de acordo com o que você deseja enviar no e-mail (imagens no corpo do e-mail, imagens em anexo, etc).

Comment: Já estive nesse website. Mas obrigado.